# How to multiprocess functions

Tags: python

How can non-iterable kwargs be included in the `map` function of `concurrent.futures`? For example, in the code below, how can `c` be called as False for all function calls of `single`? That is, `single(iterable_a[i], iterable_b[i], c=False)` where `i` is an int between 0 and 3.

```
import concurrent.futures

def single(a, b, c=True):
    return (a, b, c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    iterable_a = range(4)
    iterable_b = range(4,8)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(single, iterable_a, iterable_b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for that:

```
from functools import partial

single2 = partial(single,c=False)
```

will generate a function `single2` where `c` is set to `False`. So you can use:

```
from functools import partial

results = executor.map(partial(single,c=False), iterable_a, iterable_b)
```

So your `map` calls a function generated from `partial(single,c=False)` and you `map` with that function.